# Cucumber/gradle example not generating report?

Tags: cucumber, gradle, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm investigating using gradle and cucumber together, and found [this lovely example](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-gradle) in cucumber's github.

So, I cloned the repository and ran it myself. It failed, as it's configured to do, but I couldn't find the HTML or JSON report that it *appears* to be configured to output. I say *appear* because I'm brand new to cucumber, but this class would seem to indicate where it'll put it:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:build/cucumber-html-report", "json-pretty:build/cucumber-report.json"})
public class RunCukesTest {

}
```

However, it's not appearing in the build directory after running `gradle cucumber`.There's no cucumber-html-report directory, not is there a cucumber-report.json file. I'm running it with Java 7 and Gradle 1.6, if it matters.

Ideas? Is this a known issue with the Cucumber/Gradle integration?

Answer (score 3):

The class name changed depending on the version of Cucumber you are using. It changed from `json-pretty` to `json`.

Answer (score 1):

When running the 'cucumber' task on this example the generated cucumber report is located at 'build/cucumber-html-report/index.html'. Running the 'test' task fails as it seems that gradle has problems to create the test report for the cucumber created tests (file name contains spaces) I need to dig a bit into this to see how this can be fixed in gradle.

cheers,

René

Comment: I am running `gradle cucumber`, but there is no report in build. That's the question: why?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. when I run "gradle cucumber" I got the test report in the directory I mentioned

Comment: Weird. I literally clone cucumber-jvm with git, go to the java-gradle example, and do gradle cucumber... build only has classes, dependency-cache, libs, and tmp inside of it. I've done this on two computers, too. Is there some sort of environment variable or something I need?

Comment: sorry my fault. the report is generated when running "gradle test". I need to dig a bit deeper into it to figure out what's the problem here. maybe the cucumber guys can help out.

Comment: OK, if you add `--format blah:blah/blah` (of course, with a valid format) to the args of the javaexec that runs `cucumber.api.cli.Main`, it reports OK without having to run `gradle test` (which has some weird issues).

Answer (score 1):

The cucumber-jvm-example doesn't do reporting using `gradle cucumber`, but does do it with `gradle test`. However, `gradle test` will have a couple issues, namely showing a "null" test of sorts.

A workaround to this, if need be, is to add the formats to the args of the javaexec that runs cucumber. For example, in `build.gradle`:

```
javaexec {
    main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
    classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
    args = ['--format', 'html:cucumber-html-report', '-f', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/resources']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an error with that very same line (taken from this [tutorial](http://unmesh.me/2013/09/02/automated-acceptance-testing-ios-mobile-apps-with-appium-cucumber-jvm-jenkins-and-sauce-labs-part-2/)).
In order to resolve, had to change the third parameter from **"json-pretty" to just "pretty"**

So this is my final code line:
@CucumberOptions(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "pretty:target/cucumber-report.json"})

BTW, 
@Cucumber.Options is [deprecated](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/junit/Cucumber.Options.html), we should use [CucumberOptions](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/CucumberOptions.html)